# Can I have errors from "lein cljsbuild auto" appear in my Vim quickfix window?

Tags: vim, clojure, clojurescript

I want to be able to have errors from cljsbuild appear in my Vim quickfix window. More detail below.

I'm enjoying ClojureScript while using Vim as my editor but I want to improve my work flow.

Currently I edit in Vim and have a watcher task in another terminal that will auto build whenever I change any source. My leinengein file is configured to spawn this with

```
lein cljsbuild autobuild
```

This is great as I don't have to spin up the JVM for every compile and it's pretty quick. So the work flow is:

- Edit
- Save
- Auto compile
- Switch to the browser
- Refresh and run

Nice :) The only issue is when I get an error or warning. I have to keep an eye on the other terminal window to see if there's any error spew and then work out where the error line is by trawling through it. I'm a bit of a newb so I get a lot of errors :D

What I'd prefer is having any errors appear in Vim in my quickfix window so I can jump to them quickly while not giving up the benefits of having the cljsbuild run as a file watcher.

Is this possible? Any help gratefully received :)

gaz

Answer (score 1):

As long as the errors are shown in [stdout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29), Vim can show these errors and respective line numbers from the quickfix window.

Since I don't use clojurescript, you'll have to read Vim's documentation about [makeprg](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27makeprg%27) and [errorformat](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#errorformat). This is rather straight forward.

I've used `makeprg` with `autocmd` before, but now I let Syntastic do the work for me. Unfortunately, it doesn't support clojurescript at the moment, you could do a pull request if you get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can capture the build output into a file (by appending `> build.log` or `| tee build.log`), you can then load this into Vim's quickfix list via:

```
:cfile build.log
```

Of course, you need to set an appropriate `'errorformat'` first so that Vim is able to correctly parse it.